# Amazon Connect 2-way SMS not working with FIFO SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am trying to use 2-way SMS with Amazon Connect.

But I am getting the below error when I choose a FIFO SNS for the 2-way SMS configuration. It works fine if I select a non FIFO SNS topic.

Any solution or workaround for this issue ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Open a support ticket. Maybe Pinpoint does not support FIFO topics.

Comment: Pinpoint is listing the FIFO topic. Issue is when I click on the save button after choosing FIFO out of the list that Pinpoint displays in its dropdown. Sure will try the support route.